# Can't install phpunit and phpunit-selenium with composer

Tags: php, selenium, phpunit, composer-php

I'm trying to follow this guide https://www.sitepoint.com/using-selenium-with-phpunit/ so I can automate Chrome with PHP. I've already got this working in Python, but I'm just so much more familiar with PHP that I figured it'd be easier (maybe I'm wrong...)

Anyway, when I run

```
composer require --dev phpunit/phpunit
composer require --dev phpunit/phpunit-selenium
```

I got a whole ton of output from composer about how they both depend on different things that aren't possible to do at the same time (I think, I could be wrong here, too). My output:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - phpunit/phpunit-selenium 3.0.3 requires phpunit/phpunit ~5.0 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[5.0.0, 5.0.1, 5.0.10, 5.0.2, 5.0.3, 5.0.4, 5.0.5, 5.0.6, 5.0.7, 5.0.8, 5.0.9, 5.0.x-dev, 5.1.0, 5.1.1, 5.1.2, 5.1.3, 5.1.4, 5.1.5, 5.1.6, 5.1.7, 5.1.x-dev, 5.2.0, 5.2.1, 5.2.10, 5.2.11, 5.2.12, 5.2.2, 5.2.3, 5.2.4, 5.2.5, 5.2.6, 5.2.7, 5.2.8, 5.2.9, 5.2.x-dev, 5.3.0, 5.3.1, 5.3.2, 5.3.3, 5.3.4, 5.3.5, 5.3.x-dev, 5.4.0, 5.4.1, 5.4.2, 5.4.3, 5.4.4, 5.4.5, 5.4.6, 5.4.7, 5.4.8, 5.4.x-dev, 5.5.0, 5.5.1, 5.5.2, 5.5.3, 5.5.4, 5.5.5, 5.5.6, 5.5.7, 5.5.x-dev, 5.6.0, 5.6.1, 5.6.2, 5.6.3, 5.6.4, 5.6.5, 5.6.6, 5.6.7, 5.6.8, 5.6.x-dev, 5.7.0, 5.7.1, 5.7.10, 5.7.11, 5.7.12, 5.7.13, 5.7.14, 5.7.15, 5.7.16, 5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, 5.7.2, 5.7.20, 5.7.3, 5.7.4, 5.7.5, 5.7.6, 5.7.7, 5.7.8, 5.7.9, 5.7.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - phpunit/phpunit-selenium 3.0.2 requires phpunit/phpunit ~5.0 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[5.0.0, 5.0.1, 5.0.10, 5.0.2, 5.0.3, 5.0.4, 5.0.5, 5.0.6, 5.0.7, 5.0.8, 5.0.9, 5.0.x-dev, 5.1.0, 5.1.1, 5.1.2, 5.1.3, 5.1.4, 5.1.5, 5.1.6, 5.1.7, 5.1.x-dev, 5.2.0, 5.2.1, 5.2.10, 5.2.11, 5.2.12, 5.2.2, 5.2.3, 5.2.4, 5.2.5, 5.2.6, 5.2.7, 5.2.8, 5.2.9, 5.2.x-dev, 5.3.0, 5.3.1, 5.3.2, 5.3.3, 5.3.4, 5.3.5, 5.3.x-dev, 5.4.0, 5.4.1, 5.4.2, 5.4.3, 5.4.4, 5.4.5, 5.4.6, 5.4.7, 5.4.8, 5.4.x-dev, 5.5.0, 5.5.1, 5.5.2, 5.5.3, 5.5.4, 5.5.5, 5.5.6, 5.5.7, 5.5.x-dev, 5.6.0, 5.6.1, 5.6.2, 5.6.3, 5.6.4, 5.6.5, 5.6.6, 5.6.7, 5.6.8, 5.6.x-dev, 5.7.0, 5.7.1, 5.7.10, 5.7.11, 5.7.12, 5.7.13, 5.7.14, 5.7.15, 5.7.16, 5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, 5.7.2, 5.7.20, 5.7.3, 5.7.4, 5.7.5, 5.7.6, 5.7.7, 5.7.8, 5.7.9, 5.7.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - phpunit/phpunit-selenium 3.0.1 requires phpunit/phpunit ~5.0 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[5.0.0, 5.0.1, 5.0.10, 5.0.2, 5.0.3, 5.0.4, 5.0.5, 5.0.6, 5.0.7, 5.0.8, 5.0.9, 5.0.x-dev, 5.1.0, 5.1.1, 5.1.2, 5.1.3, 5.1.4, 5.1.5, 5.1.6, 5.1.7, 5.1.x-dev, 5.2.0, 5.2.1, 5.2.10, 5.2.11, 5.2.12, 5.2.2, 5.2.3, 5.2.4, 5.2.5, 5.2.6, 5.2.7, 5.2.8, 5.2.9, 5.2.x-dev, 5.3.0, 5.3.1, 5.3.2, 5.3.3, 5.3.4, 5.3.5, 5.3.x-dev, 5.4.0, 5.4.1, 5.4.2, 5.4.3, 5.4.4, 5.4.5, 5.4.6, 5.4.7, 5.4.8, 5.4.x-dev, 5.5.0, 5.5.1, 5.5.2, 5.5.3, 5.5.4, 5.5.5, 5.5.6, 5.5.7, 5.5.x-dev, 5.6.0, 5.6.1, 5.6.2, 5.6.3, 5.6.4, 5.6.5, 5.6.6, 5.6.7, 5.6.8, 5.6.x-dev, 5.7.0, 5.7.1, 5.7.10, 5.7.11, 5.7.12, 5.7.13, 5.7.14, 5.7.15, 5.7.16, 5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, 5.7.2, 5.7.20, 5.7.3, 5.7.4, 5.7.5, 5.7.6, 5.7.7, 5.7.8, 5.7.9, 5.7.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - phpunit/phpunit-selenium 3.0.0 requires phpunit/phpunit ~5 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[5.0.0, 5.0.1, 5.0.10, 5.0.2, 5.0.3, 5.0.4, 5.0.5, 5.0.6, 5.0.7, 5.0.8, 5.0.9, 5.0.x-dev, 5.1.0, 5.1.1, 5.1.2, 5.1.3, 5.1.4, 5.1.5, 5.1.6, 5.1.7, 5.1.x-dev, 5.2.0, 5.2.1, 5.2.10, 5.2.11, 5.2.12, 5.2.2, 5.2.3, 5.2.4, 5.2.5, 5.2.6, 5.2.7, 5.2.8, 5.2.9, 5.2.x-dev, 5.3.0, 5.3.1, 5.3.2, 5.3.3, 5.3.4, 5.3.5, 5.3.x-dev, 5.4.0, 5.4.1, 5.4.2, 5.4.3, 5.4.4, 5.4.5, 5.4.6, 5.4.7, 5.4.8, 5.4.x-dev, 5.5.0, 5.5.1, 5.5.2, 5.5.3, 5.5.4, 5.5.5, 5.5.6, 5.5.7, 5.5.x-dev, 5.6.0, 5.6.1, 5.6.2, 5.6.3, 5.6.4, 5.6.5, 5.6.6, 5.6.7, 5.6.8, 5.6.x-dev, 5.7.0, 5.7.1, 5.7.10, 5.7.11, 5.7.12, 5.7.13, 5.7.14, 5.7.15, 5.7.16, 5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, 5.7.2, 5.7.20, 5.7.3, 5.7.4, 5.7.5, 5.7.6, 5.7.7, 5.7.8, 5.7.9, 5.7.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - Installation request for phpunit/phpunit-selenium ^3.0 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit-selenium[3.0.0, 3.0.1, 3.0.2, 3.0.3].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

And this is my `composer.json` contents

```
{
    "require": {
        "giggsey/libphonenumber-for-php": "~7.0",
        "firephp/firephp-core": "0.4.0",
        "aws/aws-sdk-php": "^3.3",
        "jdorn/sql-formatter": "^1.2",
                "piwik/device-detector": "3.5.0",
                "doctrine/cache": "1.6.0",
        "php-console/php-console": "~3.0",
        "gabrielbull/ups-api": "^0.7.3",
        "google/apiclient": "^2.0",
        "jeremeamia/superclosure": "^2.3",
        "commerceguys/addressing": "^0.8.4",
        "arcreative/php-address-format": "^0.0.2",
        "commerceguys/intl": "^0.7.4",
        "ramsey/uuid": "^3.6",
        "neitanod/forceutf8": "^2.0",
        "facebook/webdriver": "^1.4",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^6.2"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
composer require --dev phpunit/phpunit
```

This will install the latest PHPUnit, which currently is at version 6.x.

```
composer require --dev phpunit/phpunit-selenium
```

This will then try to install the selenium extension, which cannot be installed because it requires PHPUnit 5.x, as you can see reading the output you get as "Problem 1".

Solution: Explicitly require PHPUnit 5, then require phpunit-selenium.

As a side note: You gave the wrong `composer.json`, it cannot be created by the command you mentioned. It should have listed PHPUnit unter `"require-dev"`.

Comment: It looks like I just omitted the `--dev` flag on the first install, that's why it wasn't in the right spot. I had to look up how to require a specific version, so the command I ran (after removing `phpunit`) was `php composer.phar require --dev phpunit/phpunit "^5"` and it's all working!